# Tech Design to achieve a workflow usability using UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

New to iOS development with a simple technical design question. The project I'm working has walks a user through a set of questions, upwards of 20. I want to use the UINavigationController to give a workflow feel in terms of usability with the back button and Next button in the navigation bar - that is a requirement. However, the design of each of the 20 views will be identical, except of course for the content which will be data driven.

From a design standpoint, would I...

1. Replicate the View Controller 20 times with 20 separate h and m classes, and use push segue's between each to give a workflow feel.
2. Replicate the View Controller 20 times but connect to same h and m class.
3. Redraw the View each time the user clicks Back or Next, thus keeping 1 viewcontroller

I've looked at several samples with xib files, but I'm looking to pull this off with the latest version of xcode and storyboards.

Comment: What you have tried till now?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach will be to reuse what has already been created. The View (From Modal-View-Controller) part of your application needs to be implemented only once.

All you need is a simple action to allow user to navigate between provide options (20 in this case).

The preferred option in this case will be

*3)Redraw the View each time the user clicks Back or Next, thus keeping 1 viewcontroller*

All you need is to update the content (equivalent to redraw the view)using proper selectors such as

```
- (IBAction)navigateToNextOption:(int)index;
- (IBAction)navigateToPreviousOption:(int)index;
```

You might also like to handle validation based on indices and prompt user to select proper navigation buttons.

A simple case say what if the options are 1000 , might also help you decide the best approach.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that use a single viewcontroller and show the animation behavior like UINavigationController on next and back button click. use this source code a Git

[kASlidshow git repositry](https://github.com/kirualex/KASlideShow)

[how it looks](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kaslideshow)

replace the arrow buttons and place it a top of the UIViewController.